# Sitecore 9.1 PaaS Analytics Graph not working

Tags: sitecore, analytics, paas

In my Sitecore PaaS instance I configured campaigns, goals etc. Added a few interactions, but when I go to Experience Analytics dashboard, I get this error:

[image]

As a result, I can't see any analytics in the dashboard.
I tried a few solutions found on the usual channels, but none of them seem to work.

Any ideas?

**[EDIT]**

All -xc- sites return 403 error

LOGS

> 8684 14:33:35 ERROR Cannot start analytics Tracker Exception:
>   System.InvalidOperationException Message: Ensure definition type did
>   not complete successfully. StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal
>   Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent,
>   Headers: {   Cache-Control: private   Date: Fri, 20 Apr 2018 14:33:35
>   GMT   Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET   Content-Length: 3420   Content-Type:
>   text/html; charset=utf-8 } Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web    at
>   Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1
>   taskFactory)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.DataStorage.ReferenceDataClientDictionary.EnsureDefinitionType(String
>   definitionTypeName)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.DataStorage.ReferenceDataClientDictionary.LoadAs[T](Object
>   key)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.AverageCounterExtensions.MeasureMilliseconds[T](AverageCounter
>   counter, Func`1 func)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.ReferenceDataDictionary`2.Get(TKey
>   key, LookupStrategy strategy)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.UserAgentsDictionary.Register(String
>   userAgentName)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.CurrentVisitContext.set_UserAgent(String
>   value)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateVisits.InitializeWithRequestData.Process(CreateVisitArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateVisits.CreateVisitPipeline.Run(CreateVisitArgs
>   args)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.StandardSession.CreateInteraction(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.InitializeTracker.CreateVisit.Process(InitializeTrackerArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.InitializeTracker.InitializeTrackerPipeline.Run(InitializeTrackerArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartTracking.StartTrackingPipeline.Run(StartTrackingArgs
>   args)    at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.StartTracking()
>
> 5736 14:32:15 ERROR Cannot start analytics Tracker Exception:
>   System.InvalidOperationException Message: Ensure definition type did
>   not complete successfully. StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal
>   Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent,
>   Headers: {   Cache-Control: private   Date: Fri, 20 Apr 2018 14:32:15
>   GMT   Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET   Content-Length: 3420   Content-Type:
>   text/html; charset=utf-8 } Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web    at
>   Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1
>   taskFactory)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.DataStorage.ReferenceDataClientDictionary.EnsureDefinitionType(String
>   definitionTypeName)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.DataStorage.ReferenceDataClientDictionary.LoadAs[T](Object
>   key)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.AverageCounterExtensions.MeasureMilliseconds[T](AverageCounter
>   counter, Func`1 func)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.ReferenceDataDictionary`2.Get(TKey
>   key, LookupStrategy strategy)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.UserAgentsDictionary.Register(String
>   userAgentName)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.CurrentVisitContext.set_UserAgent(String
>   value)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateVisits.InitializeWithRequestData.Process(CreateVisitArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateVisits.CreateVisitPipeline.Run(CreateVisitArgs
>   args)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.StandardSession.CreateInteraction(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.InitializeTracker.CreateVisit.Process(InitializeTrackerArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.InitializeTracker.InitializeTrackerPipeline.Run(InitializeTrackerArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartTracking.StartTrackingPipeline.Run(StartTrackingArgs
>   args)    at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.StartTracking()

**[UPDATE]**

I deployed a new Sitecore instance. Everything was working fine. I exported the tenant as a package from the old installation and updated the newly-created instance. And got the same error. Moreover, the experience editor is not working properly and crashes the instance.
This is the log:

> ManagedPoolThread #9 07:12:16 ERROR Could not update device detection
>   database Exception: System.ArgumentNullException Message: Null ids are
>   not allowed. Parameter name: endpointUri Source: Sitecore.Kernel    at
>   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNullOrEmpty(String argument,
>   String argumentName)    at
>   Sitecore.CES.Client.WebClient.DownloadBinaryContent(String
>   endpointUri, String resourcePath, DownladBinaryContentParameters
>   parameters)    at
>   Sitecore.CES.DeviceDetection.Providers.FiftyOneDegrees.FiftyOneDeviceDetectionClient.GetNewerVersion()
>   at
>   Sitecore.CES.DeviceDetection.Providers.FiftyOneDegrees.FiftyOneDeviceDetectionClient.DoUpdate(String
>   serviceName, String& newDatabasePath, String& newDatabaseVersion)
>   at
>   Sitecore.CES.DeviceDetection.Providers.DeviceDetectionClient.Update()
>
> ManagedPoolThread #4 07:12:16 ERROR Exception Exception:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Message: Exception has
>   been thrown by the target of an invocation. Source: mscorlib    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method,
>   Object[] parameters, Object obj)    at
>   Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)    at (Object ,
>   Object[] )    at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs
>   args)    at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String
>   pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Jobs.Job.DoExecute()    at
>   Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.AggregateException Message: One or more errors
>   occurred. Source: mscorlib    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive,
>   Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body,
>   Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1
>   source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2
>   bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4
>   bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`2 body)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.PerformUpdate(IEnumerable`1
>   indexableInfo, IndexingOptions indexingOptions)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.AggregateException Message: One or more errors
>   occurred. Source: mscorlib    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive,
>   Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body,
>   Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1
>   source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2
>   bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4
>   bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit,
>   Action`1 localFinally)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source,
>   Action`1 body)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.CompositeSearchService.PostDocuments(ICloudBatch
>   batch)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchUpdateContext.Commit()    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor.IndexModified(IProviderUpdateContext
>   context, Object document, IndexOperation operation)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchUpdateContext.UpdateDocument(Object
>   itemToUpdate, Object criteriaForUpdate, IExecutionContext[]
>   executionContexts)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchIndexOperations.Update(IIndexable
>   indexable, IProviderUpdateContext context, ProviderIndexConfiguration
>   indexConfiguration)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.UpdateItemVersion(IProviderUpdateContext
>   context, Item version, IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext)
>
>   at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.DoUpdate(IProviderUpdateContext
>   context, SitecoreIndexableItem indexable, IndexEntryOperationContext
>   operationContext)    at
>   Sitecore.XA.Foundation.VersionSpecific.Search.ItemCrawler.DoUpdate(IProviderUpdateContext
>   context, SitecoreIndexableItem indexable, IndexEntryOperationContext
>   operationContext)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.Update(IProviderUpdateContext
>   context, IIndexableUniqueId indexableUniqueId,
>   IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext, IndexingOptions
>   indexingOptions)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.<>c__DisplayClass94_2.b__0(IndexableInfo
>   info, ParallelLoopState parallelLoopState)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.b__1()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.b__0(Object )
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception:
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.BadRequestException
>   Message: Error in the request URI, headers, or body Source:
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchServiceClient.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(HttpResponseMessage
>   response)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchServiceClient.UpdateIndex(IndexDefinition
>   indexDefinition)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Schema.SearchServiceSchemaSynchronizer.SyncRemoteService(IndexDefinition
>   sourceIndexDefinition, IEnumerable`1 incomingFields)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Schema.SearchServiceSchemaSynchronizer.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.b__0()
>   at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Utils.Retryer.RetryPolicy.Execute(Action
>   action)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchService.PostDocumentsImpl(ICloudBatch
>   batch)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.SearchService.PostDocuments(ICloudBatch
>   batch)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.CompositeSearchService.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.b__0(ISearchService
>   searchService)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.b__1()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.b__0(Object )
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception:
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.AzureSearchServiceRESTCallException
>   Message: {"error":{"code":"","message":"The request is invalid.
>   Details: index.fields[0].name : The name field is required.\r\n"}}

Comment: Those errors indicate an error on the server. Have you looked at the error in the Application Insights logs? What error is being reported by Sitecore? That might help with finding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the ‘deploy definitions’ option in the Sitecore control panel?

Comment: To deploy marketing definitions, you have to rebuild indexes first